# Prove that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G, a ∈ G, n ∈ N,$ and $a^{n} ∈ K$. Then $|aK|$|$n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Prove that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G, a ∈ G, n ∈ N,$ and $a^{n} ∈ K$. Then $|aK|$|$n$.

So I know I'm supposed to use the fact that for a group $A, h ∈ A,$ and a positive m, if $h^{m}=e$, then $|h|$|$ m$, but I'm not sure how to start it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah.  K normal so G/K is a group.  aK has some order.  Since a^nK is the identity element,  use your result you presented

Comment: @dannyLara How do you know that a^nK is the identity?

Comment: Since a^n is in K,  then a^nK = K,  the identity element of G/K.

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is that $\phi:G\to G$ defined by $\phi(x)=ax$ is a bijection.  What does this tell you about $|K|$ and $|aK|$?